# Connection refused for Redis on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, redis, celery

I'm trying to set up Redis on Heroku as a backend for Celery. I have it working locally but  on Heroku, I get this error (after the celery task completes): ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting localhost:6379. Connection refused.

From what I can tell from other answers, that would indicate that the redis server isn't online, though the REDISTOGO_URL seems to be configured properly.

In settings.py:

```
REDIS_URL = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/0')
```

In tasks.py:

```
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery('tasks', backend=settings.CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND, broker=settings.REDIS_URL)
```

Versions:

```
celery==3.0.5
celery-with-redis==3.0
django-celery==3.0.4
kombu==2.3.2
redis==2.6.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. I had the celery backend configured to the string 'redis' rather than the REDIS_URL.

What I had:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis'
```

What it should be:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = REDIS_URL
```

Dmitry - appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're not using `REDISTOGO_URL`, since the error message states `localhost`

Try to check:

1. heroku config, just to check that REDISTOGO_URL is set in config
2. Go to shell on heroku (like [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#using-the-django-shell)) and see if python gets url correctly

Do you run celery on the same app, if not check that other server's config.

Comment: That was my thought too - how can I check what it's using?

Comment: REDISTOGO_URL is set correctly in the config. And Python is pulling it in as well (if I import settings.REDIS_URL, it matches the Heroku config). Celery is in the same app.

Comment: Looking through my logs, it looks like Celery is reporting the correct broker (that same REDISTOGO_URL) in its configuration.

Comment: It's hard to tell from here. I would try to setup Celery according to their django documentation, put broker into settings.py and see if that helps.